# Overwiting excel data with the next days new data

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm stuck...My python script scrapes a website for information and then uses a blank template xlsx I saved in the root dir.. But I can not figure out to get the script to overwite the previous days data. It just adds the new data up under the previous days data.
Here's is my code

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('College.xlsx')
ws = wb.active
sheet = wb.get_active_sheet()
wb.save('merged.xlsx')
```

Comment: I hope this script is sanitized?

Comment: If you don't want the values from the previous day any more, why not just create a new file for each day from the template?

Answer (score 1):

The `ws.append` method will add your data below the last used row in the column.

If you use `ws.cell(row=x, column=y) =` etc, you can target where you want your data to go.

More at the [openpyxl docs](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/api/openpyxl.cell.cell.html).

Comment: Or, delete the relevant cells and openpyxl should then append as required.